# Extracting BinaryString as Integer, need suggestions

Tags: java, string, binary, integer, xor

> PS: I tried searching many existing questions here on Stackoverflow, however it
>   only added chaos to my query!

```
10101
11100
11010
00101
```

Consider this as a sample Input, which I need to read as `BinaryString` one by one! Then I need to represent them as an `Integer`.

Obviously `int x = 20` initializes `x` as a decimal Integer,

and I read from other questions that `int y = 0b101` initializes `y` as a binary `Integer`.

Now, **The question is:** If I have a binaryString, how do I cast it into an `int` like with a preceding `0b` . My objectives following this is to perform bit level `OR` and `XOR` operations.

ie from the above input, I need to do `10101 ^ 11100`

Let me know if this is the right way to approach a problem like this, Thanks!

Comment: Hint: there's no such thing as a "decimal integer" or a "binary integer". The statements `int x = 20;`, `int x = 0x14` and `int x = 0b10100;` are *exactly equivalent*. An integer is just an integer. If I have 20 cakes, that's the same number of cakes whether I count them in binary, hex, decimal or something else...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks , I understand, so I think** performing an XOR operation on two decimal numbers is same as performing XOR on their binary** . Am I right?

Comment: @shaheen - YES, check my answer. Especially, the last paragraph.

Comment: Well, sort of - but it's simpler to just understand that there's no such thing as a "decimal number" (for integers, anyway... with floating point it becomes more complex). There's a decimal *representation* of a number (as a string) and there's a binary *representation* of a number (as a string)...

Comment: And, where can I find info to master these concepts, handling Strings and Integers in all formats, especially when coding with java? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to know how to represent Binary Strings as Integer.

Well, you can perform this task for conversion of Binary String to Integer:

```
String input = "0b1001";
String temp = input.substring(2);
int foo = Integer.parseInt(temp, 2);
```

Alternately, to switch back :

```
String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(foo);
```

> from the above input, I need to do 10101 ^ 11100.

You can achieve the same using proper decimal representation of integer. If you want to re-invent the wheel, then

1. first convert the decimal representation of the given number to Binary String(using step 2);
2. then convert to integer value using step 1;
3. repeat steps 1 and 2 for the second number; and
4. finally, perform the XOR operation over them.

But, I don't see how it'll be performing/calculating differently. It'd still be stored as the same integer. It is just that you will get extra satisfaction(on your part) that the number was read as an integer and then converted to Binary representation of that number.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`. It will throw an exception if the binary string is invalid, so you might want to validate the input.

```
String binary = "10001";
int asInt = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2); // 17
```

`int` supports `^` (bitwise XOR) operator. All you have to do is convert your binary strings to `int` variables and perform the desired operations.

Comment: this is **NOT** what I am looking for! I need the value in String binary in Int with base 2 , ie in simple I need that String as a number, say `int asInt = 0b10001`

Comment: @shaheen: Again, you have misunderstood what an `int` is. This answer *does* show you how to parse a binary string as an `int`.

Comment: @shaheen, you basically need to reimplement XOR operator with a custom `BinaryString` class? Your question is pretty chaotic.